# Make Hover area bigger

Tags: javascript, css, hover, block, area

As it shows in this link
http://wop.pt/Temp/

I've made an image which when it's Hover, a Zoom In is made and a "Tooltip" shows up, with the Text "Look inside".

But I wanted that the image doesn't Zoom Out when the user does Hover to the tooltip.

Basically what I think I need is that the Hover incorporates the Tooltip.

How can I enlarge the Area of the trigger without changing the Image?

```
   <div class="img"><a id="idCoverSchools" href="#"><img width="150" height="130" src="Images/Covers-Schools.png" alt="Interview" /></a>
            <span class="clTooltip">Look inside</span>
   </div>


.clTooltip{
    position:block;
    color:#FFF;
    display: none;
    background: #EB3431;
    margin-top:-45px;
    margin-left:13px;
    z-index: 100;
    width:100px;
    height:16px;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;}
.img {
  margin-left:-99px;
  position:inherit;
  z-index: 0;}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var cont_left = $("#idCovers").position().left;
    $("a img").hover(function() {
        // hover in
        $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 7px 5px #666");
        $(this).animate({
           height: "217",
           width: "250",
           left: "-=50",
           top: "-=50"
        }, "slow");
    }, function() {
        // hover out
        $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #CCCCCC");
        $(this).animate({
            height: "130",
            width: "150",
            left: "+=50",
           top: "+=50"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $(".img").each(function(index) {
        var left = (index * 200) + cont_left;
        $(this).css("left", left + "px");
    });
});
```

Comment: You should, your mouseout function is getting called when the user hovers the tooltip, the current answer tries to predict the most probable error you may have

Comment: But what's the solution? Isn't possible like this?

Comment: Do you really need javascript? A simple `scale transition` with css should do trick for you.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the hover action on the div embedding the image and the tooltip, not on the image itself. It should work.

Comment: Tried it but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the mouseout event is triggered when you hover over the tooltip.
So putting the hover effect on the div containing the image will solve the problem.

Comment: Like this?
    $("a img").hover(function()
to this
    $(".img").hover(function()
But didn't work. The Zoom went nuts.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answer, the hover action should be put on the div that embeds both the image and the tooltip:

```
$(".img").hover(function() {
```

because this will change the meaning of "this" inside the function, you will also have to change

```
$(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 7px 5px #666");
$(this).animate({
```

into

```
$(this).find("img").css("box-shadow", "5px 7px 5px #666");
$(this).find("img").animate({
```

on both in and out functions

http://jsfiddle.net/f817od2v/

Comment: Strange, one hour ago your code was working, but not anymore. Cleared the cache and it's the same. Is this the same with everyone?

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it! Thanks to all :)

I take your answers and apply a mixture of them.

But how can I classify your answers as right? It can be only one.

Here are the changes

HTML

```
<div id="idCover03div" class="clImg"><a id="idCoverGenealogia" href="#"><img id="idCover03img" width="150" height="130" src="Images/Covers-Genealogia.png" alt="Interview" /><span class="clTooltip">Look inside</span></a>
```

CSS

```
.clTooltip{
position:block;
color:#FFF;
display: none;
background: #EB3431;
margin-top:-45px;
margin-left:13px;
z-index: 11;
width:100px;
height:16px;
padding:3px;
text-align:center;}

.clImg:hover .clTooltip{
display:block;}

#idCovers{
text-align: center;
position: absolute;}
.clImg {
margin-left:-99px;
position:inherit;
z-index: 0;}
.end {
margin-right: 0;}
.clear {
clear: both;}
.clImg a img {
position: relative;
border: 0 solid #fff;}
```

Javascript

```
        $("#idCover03div").hover(function() {
        // hover in
        $("#idCover03div").css("z-index", 1);
        $("#idCover03img").css("z-index", 1);
        $("#idCover03img").css("box-shadow", "5px 7px 5px #666");
        $("#idCover03img").animate({
           height: "217",
           width: "250",
           left: "-=50",
           top: "-=50"
        }, "slow");
    }, function() {
        // hover out
        $("#idCover03img").css("z-index", 0);
        $("#idCover03img").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #CCCCCC");
        $("#idCover03img").animate({
            height: "130",
            width: "150",
            left: "+=50",
           top: "+=50"
        }, "fast");
    });
```